# Подсчет скрытых элементов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть фото галерея, она отображает 5 элементов, остальные скрыты при помощи свойства overflow : hiden, вопрос: как можно сделать подсчет и вывод числа скрытых элементов? Должно получиться вот так https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRZKU.png

```css
#lightgallery {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 122px;
}

#lightgallery img {
  width: 176px;
}

#lightgallery a {
  color: transparent;
}

#lightgallery a:nth-child(5) img {
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lightgallery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lightgallery">
  <a href="assets/img/light1.jpg">
    <img src="assets/img/light1.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="assets/img/light2.jpg">
    <img src="assets/img/light2.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="assets/img/light3.jpg">
    <img src="assets/img/light3.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="assets/img/light4.jpg">
    <img src="assets/img/light4.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="assets/img/light5.jpg">
    <img src="assets/img/light5.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="assets/img/light4.jpg">
    <img src="assets/img/light4.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="assets/img/light5.jpg">
    <img src="assets/img/light5.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/ - не подойдет?

Comment: @YuriyProkopets , при скрытии через `overflow:hidden` родителя, JQuery-слекторы `:visible` и `:hidden` работать не будут.

Comment: @МаксимВоробьев , а вам зачем их считать было нужно, если не секрет.

Comment: А посмотрите на фотографию которую я прикрепил к посту, такая стояла задача ) есть галерея и вывод только 5 фотографий, остальные скрыть и показать сколько скрыто, что бы пользователь знал, что там есть еще фотографии

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил свою задачу вот так, может кому пригодится, всем спасибо за помощь.

```
 var countPhoto = 0;
 countPhoto = $('#lightgallery a').length-5;
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var invisible = 0;
$('#lightgallery a').each(function(){
  if($(this).position().top > 0){
    invisible++;
  }
})
console.log(invisible);
```

```css
#lightgallery {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 122px;
  position:relative;/*обязательно*/
}
#lightgallery a{
  display:inline-block;
}
#lightgallery img {
  width: 176px;
}

#lightgallery a {
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lightgallery">
  <a href="assets/img/light1.jpg">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="assets/img/light2.jpg">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="assets/img/light3.jpg">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="assets/img/light4.jpg">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="assets/img/light5.jpg">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="assets/img/light4.jpg">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="assets/img/light5.jpg">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Странно, у меня почему то выводит в консоль все 7 фотографий, вместо скрытых 2, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: @МаксимВоробьев , для `#lightgallery` задан `position:relative`? Есть ли у неё `padding-top`?

Comment: Да задал position:relative, нет, все стили я написал сюда, перед самой галереей есть конечно другие элементы, это может как то повлиять?

Comment: Попробуйте код написать сюда: `$(function() { // тут код  })`

Comment: нет, теперь просто 0 выводит.

Comment: @МаксимВоробьев, в галерее может быть больше одного ряда видимых картинок?

Comment: в галерею выводится 5 фотографий, остальные уходят вниз и они скрыты за счет overflow: hidden, вот так выглядит если выключить overflow https://ibb.co/bEBv1p

Answer (score 1):

На чистом JS можно использовать [Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

Суть в том чтобы проверять смещение относительно viewport, если дочернее `top` смещение >= `bottom` смещению родителя, то элемент находится вне родителя.

Этот вариант не привязывается к одному ряду, можно сделать и два ряда или сто, хоть чтобы дети фото все вмещались в родителя, в любых случаях будет считать правильно.

В коде **@Геннадий Журов** вышесказанное работать не будет.

[image]

```js
const a = document.querySelectorAll('#lightgallery a')
let invisible = 0

a.forEach(el => {
  const { bottom } = el.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect()
  const { top } = el.getBoundingClientRect()

  if (top >= bottom)
    invisible++
})

console.log('Спрятанных элементов: ' + invisible)
```

```css
#lightgallery {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 122px;
  position: relative; /* important */
}

#lightgallery a {
  width: 176px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
}

#lightgallery img {
  width: 100%;
}

#lightgallery a {
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lightgallery">
  <a href="assets/img/light1.jpg">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random=1">
  </a>
  <a href="assets/img/light2.jpg">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random=2">
  </a>
  <a href="assets/img/light3.jpg">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random=3">
  </a>
  <a href="assets/img/light4.jpg">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random=4">
  </a>
  <a href="assets/img/light5.jpg">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random=5">
  </a>
  <a href="assets/img/light4.jpg">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random=6">
  </a>
  <a href="assets/img/light5.jpg">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random=7">
  </a>
</div>
```